# RegEx - How to Extract Price?

Tags: php, regex

How would I extract the dollar amount from the following string

"some text will go here and more and more and then there will be some price $34.03 but that doesn't mean the string will end"

I want to extract $34.03...also want to extract if there is no cents

"some text will go here and more and more and then there will be some price $34 but that doesn't mean the string will end"

Here I want to extract $34

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm no regex-guru, but was able to whip up the following with [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/).

```
/(\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/
```

Matches `$35.03` and `$35`. To accept formats like `$35,000.52` you would need to include `,`

```
/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/
```

This could likely be improved upon, but from my preliminary tests, it works just fine.

Comment: Sometimes there's space(s) between `$` and `\d`. So `(\$\s?[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
'/\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?/'

if(preg_match('/\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?/',$text,$matches)){
    echo $matches[0]; //which would be $34 or $34.03
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention a specific regex engine, you might have to adjust this a bit:

```
/(\$\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```

Comment: The outer capture group provides no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

What about this regexp: `\$[0-9.,]+` or `\$([0-9.,]+)` to strip the `$`?

It's simple but it does pretty much what you want, it even catches things like this: `$1,450.8934` or `$14.343`.

Of course the drawback it'd be that it'd catch `$34.54.23` as well.

Or if you want to catch only two decimals: `\$[0-9,]+\.[0-9]{2}` it'd catch the `$5.23` part of `$5.234565`.

You can use it with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`.