# Extract dollar amount from string - regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

i am hvaing a challenge trying to do this reliably for all possible strings.

Here are the possible values of $str:

> There is a new $66 price target
>   There is a new $105.20 price target
>   There is a new $25.20 price target

I want a new $dollar_amount to extract just the dollar amount from the above sample strings. e.g. $dollar_amount = 66/105.20/25.20 in above cases. How can i reliably do this with a regex statement in PHP? Thanks

Comment: You should accept answers to your previous questions. People will be more likely to want to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx - How to Extract Price?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430696/regex-how-to-extract-price)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\$([0-9]+[\.,0-9]*)/', $str, $match);
$dollar_amount = $match[1];
```

will be probably the most suitable one

Comment: what about `$123,432.543`

Comment: Doesn't strip commas though. Nope.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?\b/', $subject, $regs)) {
    #$result = $regs[0];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
(?<=     # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   \$       # Match the character “\$” literally
)
\d       # Match a single digit 0..9
   +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \.       # Match the character “.” literally
   \d       # Match a single digit 0..9
      +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)?       # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need this regular expression:

```
/(\$([0-9\.]+))/
```

What is the function that meet your needs is up to you.

You can find then regex functions for PHP here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: It will parse `$123` only from `$123,432.54`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#.+\$(.+)\s.+#
```

---

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.