# coldfusion - how to get all £values from string using regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to get all instances of a £values from a string. eg `the offer would be from £12,000 to £15,000.05 over 6 years with the allowance of 32 extras`

would return `12,000` and `15,000.05`

I think I want regex to say 'get all values between £ and white space' or perhaps 'get all values between £ that are numbers, then there may or may not be a . then there may or may not be another number then there will be white space'

I've found this [Extract dollar amount from string - regex in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247113/extract-dollar-amount-from-string-regex-in-php)

which I've turned into:

```
<cfset mystring = 'the offer would be from £12,000 to £15,000.05 over 6 years with the allowance of 32 extras'>

<cfset valuesfound = rematch('/\£([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)/', mystring) >
```

But alas valuesfound is coming up as an empty array.

Any help would be very grateful received.

Answer (score 1):

> I want regex to say 'get all values between £ and white space'

```
£(\S+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yX6lH6/1)

OR

```
(?<=£)\S+
```

`+` would repeats the previous character one or more times, so you can't get any empty string in the array list.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yX6lH6/2)

Comment: What if there's no whitespace after the number? e.g. `Selling car for £5.` Your pattern picks up the dot as well as the number.

Comment: Thank you Avinash - this looks really promising, but alas when I implement it in coldfusion like this <cfset valuesfound = rematch('(?<=£)\S+', mystring) > I get this error "Sequence (?<...) not recognized". Also I notice in your demo (what a great facility that is by the way) that you have used the /gm modifier. I think one has to apply modifiers 'in line' in coldfusion - which I think would mean addding '(?m) for (multi-line mode)' but I don't know how to do that - do you? Thank you for your help!

Comment: no, you don't need to put multiline modifier. Just remove the multiline modifier in the demo link, it will work. If the negative lookbehind won't work then go for the capturing group(1st regex).

Comment: if you used the first then you need to print the group index 1 to get the values . `matcher.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

A lax regex to capture the numbers would be:

```
£(\d[\d,.]*)
```

The number is available in capturing group 1.

This just check that there is a digit after the pound sign, and the rest can be any number of digits or decimal point `.` or thousand separator `,`.

Note that `£3.5,5.2` or `£3...,,,,2` or `£3.` or `£3,` can be matched by the regex above. But at least, it is somewhat more reasonable than getting `£-sign` as a match.

The lax regex above is only used for extracting information though. Don't use it for validation.

If you want a stronger regex:

```
£((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Example of the most crazy things that this regex can match:

```
£1
£0000
£0000.00000
£0.33
£0.234235234
£0001340590783445
£0.4
£234,444.2344
£789
£59.2
```

The thousand separator is optional, and if it is there, it must separate the whole part into group of 3's. The decimal part is optional, and allow arbitrary number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=£)\d+(,?\d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

This will only match correctly formatted numbers. [See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/gG6mO3/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<=£) # assert there's a "£" here
\d+ # consume as many digits as possible
(,?\d{3})* # consume a "," followed by exactly 3 digits, any number of times.
(\.\d+)? # finally, match "." followed by at least one digit - if possible.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset mystring = 'the offer would be from £12,000 to £15,000.05 over 6 years with the allowance of 32 extras'>
<cfset valuesfound2 = ReMatch("(\£[0-9,\.]*)", mystring)>
<cfdump var="#valuesfound2#">
```

Edit: I forgot to account for decimals, fixed.