# Regex/PHP quandry

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this awesome code:[Extract dollar amount from string - regex in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247113/extract-dollar-amount-from-string-regex-in-php)

It works great on regex101.com

But it isn't populating $match in my code and I'm not sure why (and my brain is super fried)

```
$price=38;
$dollar_regex = "/\$([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)/";
$str = "Yes [Add $3.00]";
preg_match("/\$([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)/", $str, $match);

               $fee = $match[1];
               echo "FEE is $fee. Changing price from $price to ";
               $price = $price + $fee;
               echo "$price<br>";
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex itself is correct. It stumbles over PHP string escaping here:

```
  preg_match("/\$...
               ↑
```

A single backslash just escapes the `$` sigil in double quotes. Thus the regex engine would receive it as literal `/$(...)/`.

So either use two backslashes, or enclose the dollar sign into `[$]` a charclass for readability.

Comment: Good explanation! (I need to copy this fancy arrow :D)

Comment: Just recently figured out the keyboard shortcuts (AltRight+Y/U/I/etc)