# Regular Expression for finding Price from String

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to extract a Price from a string:

Example:

```
$money='Rs.109.10';
$price=preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/u', '', $money);
echo $price;
```

Output of this example

```
.109.10
```

I'm expecting following output:

```
109.10
```

Help me to find correct regex.

Comment: The first colon is part of your expression `[^0-9.]`, therefore it is in the result. You need something like this `[^0-9]+\.?[0-9]`

Comment: Smamatti@: it is saying unknown identifier +....

Comment: Similar: [RegEx - How to Extract Price?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2430696/55075)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(\d[\d.]*)/', $money, $matches);
$price = $matches[1];
```

or, better, as @Smamatti's answer suggests:

```
preg_match('/\d+\.?\d*/', $money, $matches);
$price = $matches[0];
```

ie. allows only one dot at max in the number. And no need for explicit capture since we want the whole match, here.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$price=preg_replace('/^\D+/', '', $money);
```