# How to get the price value without currency symbol?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to get price value without currency symbol in **Product Page** for **OpenCart**. I have use following code for that. but, it is not work perfectly.

I have found and used following code. in **.tpl** file.

```
<?php
 $pricenocurrency = $price;
 $pricenocurrency  = preg_replace( '/\D/', '', $pricenocurrency  );
 echo $pricenocurrency ;
?>
```

So, I get following result. but, I want to not remove dot(.) from price.

**Default Price** = 86.02€

**I Got** = 8602

**I want to** = 86.02

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx - How to Extract Price?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430696/regex-how-to-extract-price)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal or numeric values in regular expression validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add point to preg_replace condition

```
 $pricenocurrency  = preg_replace( '/[^.\d]/', '', $pricenocurrency  );
```

if text around price could contain digit, make it a little complicated to save only points after digit

```
(?<!\d)\.|[^\d]
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solution works fine, but what if there are multiple currencies on your store.I would recommend to use default opencart functionality. Just do this,

In your controller do the following.

```
$data['price_without_symbol'] = $this->currency->format($amount,$currency_code,$currency_value,false);
```

Will result in price without currency symbol. And use it in your `.tpl` file. Recommended if your store supports multi-currency. Rest for knowledge. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this also

```
<?php
    $pricenocurrency = $price;
    $pricenocurrency  = preg_replace( '/[^0-9.]/', '', $pricenocurrency  );
    echo $pricenocurrency ;
?>
```